# Jquery Dynamic Sum of Inputs with same class

Tags: jquery, addition

I have written the following script. The first part multiplies the quantity and cost per item in a row, and adds it as the value in the ".price" input.

The second part I am attempting to dynamically update the #total value as each .price is added.  But I can't get this part to work.

```
var total; 
$('.invoice').on('focus','.current' , function(){
    // Calculate Price
    $('.qty').keyup(function(){
        var qty = $( document.activeElement ).val();
        var value = $( document.activeElement ).siblings(".cost").val();
        $( document.activeElement ).siblings(".price").val(qty * value);
    });
    // Calculate Total
    $('.price').change(function(){
           $('.price').each(function(){
              price = $('.price').val();
              total = parseInt(total) || 0 + parseInt(price) || 0;
              $('#total').val(total);
           });
    });
});
```

Comment: could you please add your html also. thanks.

Comment: You would need to declare `total` before the `each` loop and use `total = total + price;` and then assign the total after the each loop. But why are you `.keyup()` and `.change()` functions inside the `on()` function?

Comment: Also please post your html code.

Comment: I'm guessing you want something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpuck0gu/1/)?

Answer (score 1):

your calculate total part should be like below

```
 $('.price').change(function() {
   var total = 0;
   $('.price').each(function() {
     price = $('.price').val();
     total += parseInt(total) || 0 + parseInt(price) || 0;
   });
   $('#total').val(total);
 });
```

Declare the variable `total` outside each loop and sum all values and append to `#total` after each loop (not in each loop).